# Magento Category Widget in phtml

Tags: magento, widget, categories, php

I'd like to know if it's possibile load a widget in a particular part of a .phtml file.
I created an "Link category catalog" widget and I'd like to load it, I found this code:

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="6"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

I changed the id with the id of my widget but it's not working.
Anyone know how to do it?

Thank you very much to everyone.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call a widget instance either by ID:

```
 <?php
 $widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($widgetId);
 $widgetBlock = $this
                    ->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock($widget->getType(),
                                  $widget->getTitle(),
                                  $widget->getWidgetParameters());
 echo $widgetBlock->toHtml();
 ?>
```

Or by name:

```
 <?php
 $Widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load('WidgetInstanceName','title');
 $WidgetBlock = Mage::app()
                    ->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock($Widget->getType(),
                                  $Widget->getTitle(),
                                  $Widget->getWidgetParameters());                  
 echo $WidgetBlock->toHtml();
 ?>
```

Comment: Good news. Please upvote and accept if you are happy with the answer.